# Is there a way to run Colab code from local IDE?

Tags: python, api, pycharm, google-colaboratory

I'm developing a language learning app for desktop using python in PyCharm. I also have a language translation model trained in Google Colab. The model uses a method model.generate(), which takes in several parameters, of which one is input_ids. input_ids is the tokenized form of the input string. Also the translation of the string is displayed using print() in Colab.

I have an input string in my PyCharm code. I'm trying to pass this string to the model, run the code in Colab and get its translation, and the translated string needs to be returned to the app or saved somewhere where the app can read it.

TLDR; I need a way to execute Colab code from local IDE.

I tried looking up if there's a Colab API or something similar and didn't find any useful results.

Comment: It might work following this link (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/code-with-me.html#cwm_settings) and you'd probably have to run colab locally. But that would be colab > pycharm... not sure if the other way around is possible.